# Nitya Karma and Pooja Book

Tags: puja, book-recommendation, resource

Namaste!

Is there a book (pdf file) in English available for Nitya Karma and Pooja? The one I obtained is in Hindi.

http://webstock.in/001-Epics-PDF/Nitya-Karm-Pooja-Prakash/Nitya-Karm-Pooja-Prakash.pdf

An English version would be of great help.

Comment: No English version of this book is available AFAIK. You can check if it's available in ur native language. It's available for example in Bengali.

Comment: Is a Malayalam version available? If so, kindly share the link.

Comment: Jyothi- Possibly no. But not 100% sure. Anyways such kind of books will be there in every Indian languages. For eg- I have a similar Bengali book called Nitya Karma Puja Paddhati which serves the same purpose as Nitya Karma Puja Prakash. So, you can get similar books in Malayalam too. Did you check in your nearby religious book stores?